# Straight single quote: No curly single quotes in package documentation

Tags: r, documentation, package

When one creates packages a pdf documentation manual is generated.  If one copies the code from the examples in the manual one would expect the code to just run.  However, when a developer uses a single quote this gets converted to a special character (curly single quote).  This is not true of double quote.  Generally, I use the philosophy of "Use double quotes" but sometimes you need a single quote, for example in a regular expression.

**How can I force the build of package help documentation to use straight single quotes so users can cut and paste to the console?**

***MWE*** - Here is a package repo where I demonstrate this in the function `kill_bot`: https://github.com/trinker/SOdemoing

In the `@examples` I include a straight single quote that gets converted to a curly quote in the pdf manual: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/SOdemoing.pdf

I then copied from the pdf manual into an R console and get the following:

```
library(SOdemoing)
iconv(kill_bot("’"), "", "ASCII", "byte")

## > iconv(kill_bot("’"), "", "ASCII", "byte")
## ’
## [1] "<92>"
```

But what I want to see when I cut and paste is:

```
iconv(kill_bot("'"), "", "ASCII", "byte")

## > iconv(kill_bot("'"), "", "ASCII", "byte")
## '
## [1] "'"
```

Comment: I don't like the function name `kill_bot`

Comment: @Dason Yeah it probably understates my disdain for robots.

Comment: The idea of kill-bots running around is pleasing to me.  However, I know you didn't mean that because you're a horrible raptor.